# UnicodeEncodeError when trying to export dynamo db table and write to csv file

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-dynamodb, export

> C:\Users\nishkumari\Desktop>export-dynamodb -t user-prods -f csv -o user-prods.csv
>   export dynamodb: user-prods
>   Connecting to AWS DynamoDb
>   Downloading 2812 records ..... 100%
>   Total downloaded records: 2812
>   Writing to csv file.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\nishkumari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\export-dynamodb-script.py", line 11, in 
>       load_entry_point('export-dynamodb==2.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'export-dynamodb')()
>     File "c:\users\nishkumari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in **call**
>       return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "c:\users\nishkumari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
>       rv = self.invoke(ctx)
>     File "c:\users\nishkumari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
>       return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
>     File "c:\users\nishkumari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
>       return callback(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "c:\users\nishkumari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\exportdynamodb\entrypoints\main.py", line 28, in main
>       write_to_csv_file(data, output_filename)
>     File "c:\users\nishkumari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\exportdynamodb\entrypoints\main.py", line 136, in write_to_csv_file
>       writer.writerows(data['items'])
>     File "c:\users\nishkumari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 158, in writerows
>       return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
>     File "c:\users\nishkumari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 108-109: character maps to

Comment: Hi Nishita. Please spend some time explaining your error, where it happened and what is your expected behavior.

Comment: Hi, I ran the command export-dynamodb -t user-prods -f csv -o user-prods.csv which exports user-prods tables from my dynamodb to a csv format but it throws this error and only exports few records.

Answer (score 1):

exportdynamodb calls `open` without `encoding` specified [ref](https://github.com/travistrle/export-dynamodb/blob/master/exportdynamodb/entrypoints/main.py).

The default encoding for text files is "UTF-8" in most platforms except Windows.

Try `set PYTHONUTF8=1`.  It enables UTF-8 mode.  In UTF-8 mode, the default text encoding is changed to UTF-8.

See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#utf-8-mode for more information about UTF-8 mode.

Answer (score 0):

Do try below option

1. chcp 65001
2. set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8